# Is it possible to adjust the lfHeight and lfWidth of Arial in Wine?

Tags: wine, fonts

I have a text scaling problem for the Arial true type font in Wine 1.5.17. I have narrowed it down to the values lfHeight and lfWidth returned by EnumFonts.

I'm getting lfHeight = 100 and lfWidth = 39 in Wine 1.5.17.
The values for Windows 7 is lfHeight = 36 and lfWidth = 14.

Is it possible to adjust these values for the Arial font?